# Can't install stable-baselines3[extra]

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am having trouble installing stable-baselines3[extra]. Not sure if I missed installing any dependency to make this work.

Machine: Mac M1,
Python: Python 3.10.9,
pip3: pip 23.0

`!pip3 install 'stable-baselines3[extra]'`

I used the above command to install and it produced the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: stable-baselines3[extra] in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata~=4.13 in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (4.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.11 in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: gym==0.21 in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (0.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ./Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (9.4.0)
Collecting tensorboard>=2.9.1
  Using cached tensorboard-2.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
Collecting autorom[accept-rom-license]~=0.4.2
  Using cached AutoROM-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting ale-py==0.7.4
  Using cached ale_py-0.7.4-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting rich
  Using cached rich-13.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (239 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from stable-baselines3[extra]) (5.9.4)
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.7.0.68-cp37-abi3-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (31.1 MB)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources
  Using cached importlib_resources-5.10.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from autorom[accept-rom-license]~=0.4.2->stable-baselines3[extra]) (2.28.2)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting AutoROM.accept-rom-license
  Using cached AutoROM.accept-rom-license-0.5.4.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Ignoring importlib-resources: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting requests
        Using cached requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
      Collecting tqdm
        Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libtorrent (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for libtorrent
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: try `pip install git+https://github.com/carlosluis/stable-baselines3@fix_tests`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html#bleeding-edge-version) says you can install directly from Github, this worked ok for me

```
pip install git+https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, there is a dependency which needs a Python version < 3.9. I think creating an environment with Python 3.9 or lesser might work.

```
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Ignoring importlib-resources: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
```